# NSReadPixel() always returns nil

Tags: macos, appkit, nswindowcontroller, nsevent, nscolor

I want to create a color picker. So I thought using `NSReadPixel` would be a good approach to receive the pixels’ color. So what I basically did was this:

```
class CustomWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {

        let mouseLocation = NSEvent.mouseLocation()
        let pickedColor = NSReadPixel(mouseLocation)

    }

}
```

But `pickedColor` always returns `nil`. Even if I try to "readPixel" with a fixed point (for testing purposes) it still returns `nil`. What am I missing?

**EDIT #1**

I’ve followed the `NSBitmapImageRep` / `colorAt` approach from the answers and noticed that the resulting NSColor seems to be a bit different (in most cases brighter) that it should be (take a look at the screenshot). Do I have to consider colorSpaces or so? (and how?)

[image]

**EDIT #2**

Got it work - `bitmap.colorSpaceName = NSDeviceRGBColorSpace` does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't work. I use this code for getting pixel color

```
NSPoint _point = [NSEvent mouseLocation];

CGFloat x = floor(_point.x);
CGFloat y = [NSScreen mainScreen].frame.size.height - floor(_point.y);
//it needs because AppKit and CoreGraphics use different coordinat systems

CGWindowID windowID = (CGWindowID)[self windowNumber];

CGImageRef pixel = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectMake(x, y, 1, 1), kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow, windowID, kCGWindowImageNominalResolution);

NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:pixel];
CGImageRelease(pixel);

NSColor *color = [bitmap colorAtX:0 y:0];
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: I’ve noticed that the resulting color isn’t the exact same than in the picked pixel (see my edit above). Would you please be so kind and take a look at it? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Try to calibrate it - create image with confidently different colors and explore with your picker. May be x±1 y±1 solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks again! `colorSpaceName` had to be set.